# What that alternate connector is for on the Xbox360 controller?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

If you look at wired Xbox360 controller it has what looks like 2 filters on its wire near  USB connector. I only recently noticed that that bigger filter is actually an alternate connector with strange pin configuration. What is it for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you're talking about the inline release seen here

[image]

You can read about it at [this page on xbox.com](http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-360/accessories/connecting-game-controllers). It's a safety mechanism that allows that part to release rather than having the controller pull your console off a table or something if someone were to trip on the cord, etc.